# Formatting a text written in a string type field in AX 2012?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Is it possible in AX 2012 to find a particular word/words written in a string type field in AX 2012 table or form based on mouse selection. e.g, I have a field named Memo in my table named test. In that field I have a written a text as:

Hello, We need to confirm you that your < mobileNumber > is successfully attached with your account no. < Account >.

Now, if I open a form and select(highlight) a text **mobileNumber** written in text field using a mouse. Is it possible to do a formatting for the selected word(mobilenumber).
I need to clarify that, by formatting I mean to modify the display style of that text(e.g, BOLD, ITALIC, UNDERLINE etc.)

OR, Can I add a text field which have all the formatting options available similar as in below figure.
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that can't be done.

Comment: An alternative approach, let your users format a word template "If your system administrator has installed the Office Add-ins for Microsoft Dynamics AX, you can use the Office Add-in for Microsoft Word to create Word documents and Word templates that contain data from tables that you select in Microsoft Dynamics AX." http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801191.aspx

Comment: Thanks all for replying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have researched a lot and actually found a solution. Yes, it is true that we cannot add RichTextBox directly as a control in forms for AX2012 But it can be acheived using class named

**"SysInetHTMLEditor"**

Just run the above class and see the magic as
[image]

It is a separate form in AX 2012, to add richtextbox and controls we can use some methods written in SysInetHTMLEditor class.

In following link, Microsoft have included Richtext as a :FormControlType System Enumeration [AX 2012]
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formcontroltype.aspx

I am sure, Microsoft will include Richtextbox as a controltype in future updates for Ax2012.